# How to run a javascript animation after click of a php submit

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to start a javscript annimation and then submit a form. I have this but it's not working... I understand php is server side and javascript is client side; however, this works with alerts as long as I get rid of the header so I am confused why it wont work with my annimation.

```
if (isset($_POST['play'])) {

    if ($mSecs >= .1) {
        echo "<script>
        spinWheel_1.startAnimation();
        </script>";
    }
sleep(5);
header("Location: winwheel.php");   
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `spinWheel_1` is defined on the newly loaded page after the post request?

Comment: (try to open the console in the browser, and you will see)

Comment: I am just getting this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Comment: Error on which line of code? Look at that and debug it yourself. / I didn't downvote, but probably because it falls under the category "simple typographical error".

Comment: You can't sed the header after sending an output.

Answer (score 1):

You instruct the browser to immediately navigate away by sending the `header`. This is the reason why you see your animation without the `header` in the script.

Also, note that you cannot send the header after sending any output as a response.

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.